# Context free grammar to language

Tags: context-free-grammar

Suppose we have $G(V,Σ, R, S)$ where
$$\begin{array}{ll}
V & = \{a,b,A,B,S\}\\
Σ & = \{a,b\}\\
R &= \left\{ \begin{array}{rl} S &→ abA,\\
S&→B,\\
S&→baB,\\
S&→e,\\
A&→bS,\\
B& →aS,\\
A&→b \end{array}\right\}\end{array}$$

What is language $L(G)$ ? 
thanks in advance

Comment: Is this homework? First try listing several examples from L(G).

Comment: In fact a solution to this question exemplifies a simple but useful technique, and closing it after only five hours with almost no feedback to the OP is petty.

Comment: @Brian: You're right. Alihuseyn, I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the only production with $B$ on the left is $B\to aS$, so we can remove that production if we replace every $B$ on the righthand side of a production by $aS$. We then have the following productions:

$$\begin{align*}
&S\to abA\mid aS\mid baaS\mid \epsilon\\
&A\to bS\mid b
\end{align*}$$

We can repeat the procedure to eliminate the non-terminal symbol $A$:

$$S\to abbS\mid abb\mid aS\mid baaS\mid\epsilon\;.$$

Now it’s easy to see what language is being generated: it’s actually a regular language, which you can describe either in words or by a fairly simple regular expression.